# How to use c Sonar plug in for C projects

Tags: c, sonarqube

Have sonar2.14, sonar c plugin, sonar-runner-1.0.jar in my machine. I am able to start sonar using the command sonar.sh console and in the browser using the following URL http://localhost:port_No i am able to see the GUI.

My question is how I can use this sonar to analyse the C code. Should I use any sonar command at the time of compilation.Eg: For java we use maven sonar.

In the same way is there any command for C. Please let me know in detail with a simple example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is explained on http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/installation-and-usage/ with even a example application... What are you missing?